# Are licenses affected if the author adds conflicting clauses alongside?

Tags: license-compatibility, restrictions

I see this one quite a lot: an author releases something under a standard free/open license (i.e. *not* a [crayon license](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1445/175)), but on the same release page adds a clause that conflicts with the license. I.e.

> **Free Frobnicator** is a handy utility that frobs widgets, by Jane Doe
>
> Released under <license>
>
> By the way, <additional clause that conflicts with license>

These additional clauses could be from misunderstanding the license, or carelessness. I've seen these:

- "Let me know if you use this in your project!"

  As far as I'm aware, no free/open license requires contacting the author if you use it.
- "Contact me if you want to use this commercially."

  Implying that the license doesn't already allow commercial use, which free/open licenses do.
- "You are free to use however you want, except in pornography."

  Free/open licenses can't discriminate on usage.

**Do these extra conflicting clauses make the license invalid, or is the license unaffected?** Does it depend on the license used? Or is this legally ambiguous?

Comment: Or a closer example, Stack Exchange's attribution guidelines conflict with the CC BY-SA license!

Comment: @curiousdannii are you talking about [this](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)? If so, I'm not sure if it's conflicted, as the CC BY licenses give authors flexibility in choosing the manner of attribution. This may be a good separate question though.

Comment: I've asked about it at [law.Se] and will mention it when I write an answer to this question.

Comment: @curiousdannii Provided you're talking about [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), it is pretty obvious that this is not in any way *enforceable*.  But this is mainly a *blog post*, where Jeff Atwood airs his *opinions* about what he thinks should be "fair attribution". The fact that it officially linked may make it *appear* as something *more* than random opinions, but random thoughts is really all it is. IMHO, this does not even count as an *attempt* to tamper with the license grants of CC BY-SA.

Comment: @FreeRadical I mean [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258032/256282). The SE staff at the moment appear to be treating that blog post as much more than random thoughts.

Comment: @curiousdannii. I see no evidence that SE staff is treating this as much more than random thoughts. Quote: "I'm not a lawyer; if something like this went to court, I don't know exactly where the line would fall between 'doing the bare minimum necessary' and 'flagrantly violating the intent of the license'." I.e., so far SE has not yet tried to take this to court, and when some staffer posts about it, it is pointed out that it is *not* posted by a lawyer. It would not have been *that* difficult to get an opinion from a lawyer, and post it, if they wanted this to look as more than hot air?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are asking three questions, I think:

1. are they enforceable?
2. do they tamper with the enforceability of the main license?
3. do they pollute the open/free status of the overall license?

The answer to the third question is 'yes'. If someone adds a clause that is incompatible with, for example, OSI, then it's not an OSI-licence. This has no legal implication at all. It's just a fact.

The first two questions are for lawyers, but, in general, crayons are contagious. If you scribble on a license with a crayon, the results can very possibly be crayon-ish, since by ignorance the extra provisions can conflict with or change the interpretation of the base license.

Answer (score 10):

The concise, well-written [answer by bmargulies](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1465/997) does miss *one* thing in your question:

> Does it depend on the license used?

**Yes,** it does. The GNU GPL, for instance, specifically says that conflicting provisions are void if they add restrictions. This is from section 7 of v.3; v.2 had the corresponding text in its section 6.

> All other non-permissive additional terms are considered “further restrictions” within the meaning of section 10. If the Program as you received it, or any part of it, contains a notice stating that it is governed by this License along with a term that is a further restriction, you may remove that term.

Other licences that do not have such a clause *may or may not* be affected; I'm not a lawyer. (But it seems to me that a comment "alongside" the licence is probably meant to be *part of* the licencing terms, so yes, I think it'd be affected.)

Comment: Of course, note that if provisions in the GPL text can overrule non-GPL provisions, then vice-versa other provisions can overrule GPL provisions. The GPL does not have legal priority. Using the third example: "You are not allowed to use this software for pornography, or distribute it to people who will do so. Otherwise, you are allowed to use and distribute the program under the terms of the GPL". This explicitly states that the GPL terms does NOT have priority. To invoke section 7, the receiver must show that GPL applies, which in turns means that the "otherwise ... "  condition is met.

Comment: Nah, because anyone can distribute it again, they are void. In your example: A gets the program because he is not using it for porn or distributes it to porn people. He now has the right to give it to B with GPL attached. **Only** the GPL applies now to B, **not** the additional restriction. Now B can give the software to A to use for porn legally!  The FSF lawyers are clever folks, you can't cheat their intentions that easy.

Comment: @MSalters: As I see it, either the GNU GPL applies to the program, and so the other conditions are void; or something *like* the GNU GPL applies (modified by your other conditions), in which case the Free Software Foundation would like a word about their copyright on the text of the GPL...

Comment: @Josef: 600 char comment limit. Of course you need to make that condition sticky like the GPL itself. That's why I summarized it as "or distribute to people who will do so" - the clause needs to be as viral as the GPL.

Comment: @TimPederick: The resulting license is indeed not the GPL, as your rights are a subset. The FSF is in for an interesting discussion: is _referencing the GPL_ a violation of their copyright?

Comment: @MSalters: I think that's a bit different to what's been asked here. A licence would be merely *referencing* if it said something like, "You have all the permissions the GPL would give you, except..." But then it's not under the GPL at all and the original question doesn't apply. Hence I'm saying either the GPL applies and the extra bit is void, or your new text is a **derivative** of the GPL. (One last alternative: if you're right and the GPL *doesn't* take precedence, then s.12 kicks in: "If you cannot ... satisfy simultaneously your obligations ... you may not convey it at all".)

Comment: @MSalters how would you do that? Like you wrote it, if I don't use it for pornography (i don't) and don't distribute it to people who will do so (I don't) I can distribute it under the GPL terms. That's exactly what you have written. But then, the GPL gives me the right to distribute it anyone without that restrictions, and anyone I give that program to doesn't even need to know the initial restrictions. So granting me all GPL rights **after** I comply to something doesn't work. If you add the restrictions in another way, the GPL gives me the right to remove them.

Comment: @Josef: Standard GPL logic, but applied to the new conditions as well: You may only distribute it under the same license terms, to people accepting those terms. For the same reason you can't strip terms from the GPL, you can't strip this condition either. (And if you disagree and claim that terms _can_ be removed, fine, then I remove section 7 from the GPL)

Comment: @MSalters No. Either I can remove this, or you are **not** using the GPL! If you remove parts, it is a copyright violation to call your license GPL! (see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#ModifyGPL )

Comment: @Josef: I'm not calling it the GPL. That would in fact be recursive, as this license (conditionally) incorporates the GPL by reference.

Comment: if you incorporate the full GPL, I can remove other clauses. If you remove parts from the GPL and call it something else, you are using a crayon license and this is not relevant to the question. If you remove parts from the GPL and call it GPL, it is copyright infringement!

Comment: @Josef: Huh. I hadn't read that entry before. I would've thought they'd be *against* GPL derivatives for just the reasons they describe. Anyway, I've deleted my comment as it was thoroughly incorrect, but I think this part bears repeating: "as I said in my earlier comment, I think we're a bit far afield. Either it's under the GNU GPL, or it's a crayon license and so not the situation that the question was about."

Answer (score 6):

You say that you add this stuff on the project's "release page" (presumably the same place where people can download a release).  This is not in *any way* enforceable.  When you make free software publicly available, people can share it with anybody *without* ever seeing your release page, so users may not been made aware of your terms. No court is going to let you enforce any such terms.

In all jurisdictions I am aware of, including the EU and the USA, when you have a specific *legal* document such as a license or a contract, a court will *refuse* to look at anything except the specific license or a contract and any additional document *specifically* mentioned in the license or contract, to settle any dispute between two parties.

This means that if you put *anything* on the project page that conflicts with the main license, it will be considered null and void. I.e.:

- This is not enforceable.
- It will not tamper with the enforceability of the main license.
- It will not even  pollute the open/free status of the main license.

The same goes for a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) written by the project head and linked from every project page. Sharing your thoughts about what you think *should* be "fair attribution" is fine, but it only counts as a *suggestion*. When staffers sometimes [pretend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258032/256282) that is more than that, such pretense does not change its legal status to being a *requirement* that can be enforced by *legal means*. I.e. such additional notes, in the shape of blog posts or otherwise, can *not* be enforced through courts, and will not tamper with, or pollute the main license.

I.e.: Doing this will *not have any* effect at all on the project's licensing situation.

However. it may identify the project head as a bozo and potentially quarrelsome (NB: I am not saying that this makes the project head a bozo, etc., only that it may make some people may *think* so).  This may make some people stay away from using code from the project.  As for the SE, the (then) project head's [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) goes on to *name and shame* two specific websites that does not live up his attribution expectations.  This sort of enforcement technique is IMHO not an *ethical* way to enforce your additions to a license, but if you don't want this to happen to you, you may need to *follow* the SE recommendation if you reuse materials from SE, even if lacks any *legal* foundation.

However, *some* licenses such as the GPL *allows* additional terms. Read below the line for a more specific analysis of various ways of adding additional notices and how this applies to specific licenses.

Disclaimer: [IANAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL) and all that.

---

The text *above* the line is my answer.

However, looking beyond the "project page" it may also be interesting to look at attempts to add additional terms to the projects distribution archive.

For instance, let us assume that you add your additional terms *below* the license text is the license file (e.g. `LICENSE.txt`) included in the distro.

If you try to add or remove *anything* to or from license *itself*, the license is no longer a recognized free software license. Doing so will *make* your license a crayon license (this is more or less how crayon licenses are defined), with all the [problems](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-can-a-crayon-license-be-a-problem) that follows from the use of crayon licenses.

But what if you put your additional terms is a separate document? E.g. you but your terms in a file named `EULA.txt`, `NOTICE.txt`, `README.txt`, or some other conspicuous name) that lives in the distribution archive *along* with `LICENSE.txt` when people download the project directly from you.

Then you need to read the license text to find out whether this is permitted and if it will be enforceable. By means of example, I shall look at two popular free software licenses, GPLv3 and MIT:

- [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) very explicitly *allows* additional terms (see sec. 7. Additional Terms). but *only* if they provide additional *permissions* to the user, or "supplement the terms of this License with terms" [followed by a bullet list of six permitted types of additional terms]. Any *other* additional terms are not allowed, and permission to delete them is *explicitly* granted downstream recipients:

  > All other non-permissive additional terms are considered “further restrictions” [...].  If the Program as you received it, or any part of it, contains a notice stating that it is governed by this License along with a term that is a further restriction, you may remove that term.
- [MIT/Expat](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) grants a series of permission "without restriction".  If you add terms somewhere in the distribution that *contradict* the license grant by imposing some restrictions, these would not be enforceable if the language used do not make it clear that the intent of the drafter was to provide a precondition or a covenant for use. If this additional document is *not* a license, then it will be ignored by courts (see my introduction).  If it is an additional license, then, as explained in [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1415/606) it would amount to dual licensing and users would be free to pick the permissive license (MIT) that is provided over the more restrictive (the EULA).

There is no room here to run through *all* recognized free software licenses, but my general impression is that they do not give you much opportunity to impose restrictions on your users.  I cannot completely rule out that there exists a free software license that cuts more slack than GPLv3 or MIT/Expat - but I doubt it.

However, for all free software licenses, provided you hold the sole copyright, *or* have permission from all contributors (e.g. through a [Contributor License Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributor_License_Agreement)), adding terms that gives *further permissions* are generally allowed.

For instance you add a file with the following notice to a the distribution of a project licensed under MIT/Expat:

> To the extent allowed by applicable law, I waive the right of attribution, and the requirement that a copyright notice and a permission notice shall be included in the program.

Such a waiver would allow people to reuse your code without having to comply with the attribution, etc. requirements of the license.  If you add the following *restriction* to the waiver:

> Removing this waiver is not allowed.

Then, that would not be enforceable, as it contradicts the main license grant.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the good answers of [bmargulies](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1465/55) and [Free Radical](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1466/55) there is a perspective beyond the legal stuff.

If you release something under an open source license, your express intent is to give others some rights, including the right to redistribute, use it without restriction and to modify and release the modified work. If you do not intent to grant these rights, you don't need to add a license at all.

But the contradicting clauses cause confusion. Especially people not experienced with the legal stuff, might be shying away from using their rights on your work. So you lose possible applications of your work against your intent. Even if you legally clearly know what you do is legally working, such confusion might lead to you losing possible users.

An example that shows how legal uncertainty lead to problems, although the reason of the legal uncertainties isn't an additional clause. The german programmer [Jörg Schilling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6rg_Schilling) is well known as the programmer of cdrtools. At some point he decided to [change the license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdrtools#License_compatibility_controversy) on most of his work, while still incorporating some GPL-work. Jörg Schilling is sure, he isn't violating the GPL in this case as he expressed, and at no point any legal action happened (as far as I'm aware), this controversy didn't go to court. Still most binary Linux-distributions (source distribution is unaffected) removed cdrtools and use a fork named cdrkit. So, however the real legal situation is, the uncertainty alone lead to a lot of lost users.

So it is generally  advisable to avoid confusion as much as possible.